# SQL identify no duplicate rows from table 1 and move to table 2

Tags: sql

hi guys would like to ask if someone know how to move a data from table 1 to table 2 with no duplicates , I had use no exists but this is not the solution that i seek of ...as the case was below :

Table 1 - will keep getting imported data from external sources
Ex:

```
Batch     DeliveryOrder  DO
1001           A001     B001
1002           A002     B002 
.               .        .
.               .        .
```

Table 2 - will need to keep data of table 1 with an added unique id as primary key
Ex:

```
 ID     Batch    DeliveryOrder   DO
 1      1001       A001         B001
 2      1002       A002         B002
```

Since table 1 data has no unique value as everyday new data will keep importing with different combinations , it is hard to create a real unique row with unique id and move to table 2

I had tried

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
(Batch,DeliveryOrder)
Select Table1.Batch,Table1.DeliveryOrder
FROM Table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT DeliveryOrder 
FROM Table2 
WHERE table2.DeliveryOrder = table1.DeliveryOrder)
```

I know this is the solution but is not the correct one as my combination row of data will be different , if duplicate DO exists in different rows in table 1 ,when it move to table 2 it become unique and only 1 data had been move to table 2

I need to identify if entire row data not exists in table 2 then move the unique row of whole data to table2 from table 1 .. is there a solution that can be done ?

I am sorry for my bad English and i am not so good in SQL either

Comment: Try `DISTINCT`  in the select, as that seems to be duplicated

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
INSERT INTO Table2 
(Batch,DeliveryOrder)
Select Table1.Batch,Table1.DeliveryOrder
FROM Table1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT DeliveryOrder 
FROM Table2 
WHERE table2.DeliveryOrder = table1.DeliveryOrder AND table2.Batch = table1.Batch)
GROUP BY Table1.Batch,Table1.DeliveryOrder
```